# css border radius bug in chrome with percentages

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Hi I'm having troubles with a problem in chrome. I think it might be a bug but I can't find much info on it. Basically I want to apply border radius on an image. The border-radius will be 50% forming a circle. The reason I've set it as a % is because i wont explicity know the width/hieghtt of the image.

Any ideas why chrome doesn't display the border correclty? I haven't tested in FF < 4. but FF4 works well as does IE for a change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way around it, by adding the border and the border-radius onto the parent . I then applied the border radius to the image too. Although there is a minute gap It works in chrome now. I haven't tested it in FF3.6. But FF4 displays the same result

Comment: I was just about to write this answer .

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do?  Do you want a circle to appear behind the image?  That is what I see in FF.  In Chrome, the circle is clipping the edges of the image.

According to the spec -- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-clipping -- content is supposed to be truncated.

> The content of replaced elements is
>   always trimmed to the content edge
>   curve.

Which, to me, means that Chrome is following the spec correctly on this.

Answer (score 2):

Webkit doesn't currently clip corners of images. Remove the `src` tag from the image and you'll see that the border is being rounded correctly.

One workaround is you could set the `background-image` property in css: http://jsfiddle.net/tEzwJ/

Comment: Thanks for this. I did know of the background-image as a solution, but didn't really want to go down this route. But it might be the only solution. Its an odd choice for webkit not to clip images

Comment: I'd file it as a webkit bug, since even if you have `<div class="rounded-corners"><img src="..."/></div>` the containing image isn't even clipped! This page provides some more useful examples as well: http://www.bradclicks.com/cssplay/BorderImageAndRadius.html